# How to get system date in R5Rs in Scheme/DrRacket

Tags: date, scheme, system, r5rs

In DrRacket IDE, I was able to get the system date in the following manner when the language setting was 'Swindle':

```
(define currentMonth 0)
(let ((date (seconds->date (current-seconds))))
  (set! currentMonth (date-month date))
  )
```

Now, I need to do the same in R5Rs, but not sure how to. May I please seek your advise/help on this..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no date-time support in R5RS. The procedures `current-seconds`, `seconds->date` and `date-month` should be available in the R5RS implementation of PLTRacket as extensions.