# What extension allows access to time function in r5rs?

Tags: time, scheme, r5rs

A [4-year-old old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295727/how-to-get-system-date-in-r5rs-in-scheme-drracket/4297413#4297413) suggests that one might be able access the current-seconds and related functions in the r5rs language.

Here's why I ask: I'm a high school teacher new to Racket and we are using the r5rs language. I would like to introduce students to functions by starting with a function that needs no arguments to make sense. The example that occurs to me is minutes-past-the-hour. But I am ignorant of how to make those functions recognized in an r5rs program.

Thanks for any helpful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why not use `#lang racket` instead of r5rs? Racket is very much built with education in mind. It even has various teaching languages for use with the [How to Design Programs](http://htdp.org/) textbook (or its [second edition](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), which is still being worked on).

---

Racket's implementation of R<sup>5</sup>RS is intentionally limited—it's not usually intended to be used for anything practical, since Racket itself has outgrown its Scheme roots. It can be useful as a teaching tool, but as you've seen, it doesn't include any special extensions (beyond a small set of internal forms).

If you're really interested in using R<sup>5</sup>RS Scheme, there exists an implementation of [SRFI 19: Time Data Types and Procedures](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-19.html) bundled with Racket. R<sup>5</sup>RS does not have a module system, so there is no formally-specified way of loading external libraries in pure Scheme. You'll need to use the Racket `#%require` extension to load the SRFI implementation:

```
(#%require srfi/19)
```

This will give you access to all the SRFI 19 functions and values.

You could also just include the functionality you want from Racket itself, since the languages are actually interoperable. To include `current-seconds`, you'd want to do something like this:

```
(#%require (only racket/base
                 current-seconds))
```

If you're going to do that, though, it seems almost pointless to use the `r5rs` language. Just use `racket` or `racket/base` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much, particularly for including the sample syntax. I aim to switch languages this summer, but right in mid-stream here, I should probably stick to the horse whose idiosyncrasies and error messages I know a little about.